# Why does this basic cin prevent my program from compiling?

Tags: c++

I've included  and am using the standard namespace, and the program runs just fine when I just hard code the file name into in, but when I put in that cin VS gives me weird errors.
I'm specifically talking about the cin >> sodokuFile line, for clarity.

```
cout << "Assignment 2\n\n";
ifstream ins;
cout << "Please enter the Sokoku file\n";
string sodokuFile;
cin >> sodokuFile;
ins.open(sodokuFile.c_str());

if(ins.is_open())
{
    int num;
    //counting numbers displayed horizontally
    int counth = 0;
    //counting numbers displayed vertically
    int countv = 0;
    while (ins >> num)
    {
        cout << num << "   ";
        counth++;
        //placing vertical lines
        if(counth %3 == 0)
        {
            cout << "| ";
        }
        //making line breaks for new rows
        if(counth == 9)
        {
            cout << "\n\n";
            counth = 0;
            countv++;
            //horizontal lines
            if(countv %3 == 0)
            {

                cout << "_________________________________________\n";
            }
        }
    }   
}
else
{
    cout << "File does not exist\n";
    return 0;
}

return 0 ;
```

Here is the only thing in the compiler errors that looks useful
error C2679: binary '>>' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Comment: Oh, *weird* errors, as opposed to ordinary errors... maybe it's a compiler bug. If only there was a way to know what those errors were.

Comment: What is are the first errors?

Comment: not sure why u get errors, but cin will give you just single word on line in the end (F.e. if you write "Hello world", then you get just "Hello"), you should probably use: std::getline(std::cin, std::string);

Comment: @KerrekSB I think people must think that because the errors were not helpful to them, they are not helpful to anyone.

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi: **Surely** nobody would put spaces in their filenames now, would they?!

Comment: ¤ My ESP circuit reports that you have forgotten to include some relevant header, just as you forgot to list the complete program here, and just as you forgot to specify the "weird" errors. Actually it was not that hard to guess that you forgot, given that you forgot so much in your posting here. Relevant headers include `<iostream>` and `<string>`. I would guess the first since apparently you managed to compile a declaration of a `string` variable just fine. On the other hand, maybe that also caused some compilation error, and you just forgot to mention it? Cheers & hth.,

Comment: @SethCarnegie, that was it, thanks. Am still brand new to C++.

Comment: As a general observation, don't use `>>` to input a filename, because `>>` will only read the first "word" of input, and a filename can contain spaces. Use instead `std::getline`, from the `<string>` header. Cheers,

Answer (score 6):

You need to put

```
#include <string>
```

At the top of your file because the `string` header declares `operator>>(istream&, string&)`.