# Cin not working? I indentified the string

Tags: c++

```
cout << "Please enter the name you wish to have: ";
string Name;
cin >> Name;
```

I have identified the string, but I am getting errors with the cin saying 'error C2679: binary '>>': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion).'

I'm a beginner, obviously, so any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/q/6320995/560648, ish. And http://stackoverflow.com/a/9251816/560648. And a million others. Next time please search before asking: being a beginner does not prevent that!!

Answer (score 1):

You are using Visual Studio and forgot to

```
#include <string>
```

Comment: I'm really stupid, I thought I had tried that and it did not work, but alas, I am just not a smart person. Thanks!

Comment: @tiert Always include the proper headers for the functions and types that you use.